# like clause with N'UTF-8Text' in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I want to run this SQL query in my MySQL using HQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `tip` WHERE `tip`.`tip_title` like N'Text'
```

how can I do this with Hibernate `setParameter`?

// update

in comments, people asked me about the expected result.

I have utf-8 text in my DB (in Persian language and some times it contains both English and Persian).

so when I wanted to fetch them with `=` or `like` it gives me wrong result sometimes. so I found out I have to use `N` with my `like` statement and this is why do I want to do that.

if there is a better way to do that please tell me

Comment: I know `IN` im not sure about `N` ?

Comment: `N` operator doesn't exist in HQL

Comment: @MikeAdamenko so what should I use instead to get the same result?

Comment: depends on what you want. Describe more precisely your desire.

Comment: Can you please tell us your expected result ? So that we can suggest you something.

Comment: @sForSujit I updated my question